# How to use session variable in URL through ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, href, session-variables

I have an aspx page
There is a hyperlink to another page with some parameters. The parameters to pass is stored in Session variables.

I tried like below

```
<a href="Home.aspx?C="+<%= Session("id").ToString()%>>Home</a>
```

> The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

**Edited**

I changed  () to []

Home

Now no error but when clicking the link the page is coming but the URL is

```
Home.aspx?C=
```

The session value is not displaying

I am getting below error. Is it not possible to access the session variable like above in aspx page?

Comment: Use square brackets for session, i.e. `Session["id"]` , as its not a function.

Comment: @ShaminderSAujila yup i replaced. now the error gone but when i click on the link im getting the URL up to Home.aspx?C=

Comment: Is this VB or C#?  In VB the square brackets would be a syntax error, the parentheses would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This URL:

```
<a href="Home.aspx?C="+<%= Session["id"].ToString()%>>Home</a>
```

Would produce something like this:

```
<a href="Home.aspx?C="+someValue>Home</a>
```

Which is invalid markup.  The value should be *inside* the double-quotes, and shouldn't include that `+`:

```
<a href="Home.aspx?C=<%= Session["id"].ToString()%>">Home</a>
```

This would produce something like:

```
<a href="Home.aspx?C=someValue">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

`<a href='<%= "Home.aspx?C="+Session["id"].ToString %>'>Link</a>`

Comment: @ShaminderSAujila thanks...but this give me error.thanks for the effort..below answer solved  by issue